# Keyboard controls with jquery -> keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on my box a button:

```
<div id="close" class="close">CLOSE</div>
<div id="infocontent" class="infocontent">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
```

and my jquery code is:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
   $('#infocontent').hide();
   $('#infocontent').addClass('cnthidden');
});
```

I tried so to setup keyboard function to enable my box, but that's not true, any idea?

```
if($('#infocontent').hasClass('cnthidden')) {
 $.keydown(function() {
     $('#infocontent').show();
  });   
}
```

I need simple to enable this box if i use keydown...

Comment: What is `$.keydown` supposed to do? You need to bind the `keydown` to an element.

Comment: i have seen in jquery doc:
$( "#target" ).keydown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
but i can't understand, what is this "$( "#target" )", because i need keyboard function, if i use keydown then .show() on my box

Comment: `keydown` is a keyboard event which needs to be bind to an element.

Comment: The `$('#target')` is an element on the page. `keydown` requires you to have an element to bind it to. You should use `$(document)` to reference the document element of the page if you want the `keydown` function to run every time the key is pushed down.

Comment: Nunners, many thanks because this issue with "$(document)" was a useful explanation for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind that keydown event to an element. Assuming you want to show the box on `document keydown`,

```
 $(document).keydown(function() {
    if($('#infocontent').hasClass('cnthidden')) {
       $('#infocontent').removeClass('cnthidden');
       //assuming cnthidden has display:none property
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thanke you, i needed this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
$('#close').click(function() {
   $('#infocontent').hide();
   $('#infocontent').addClass('cnthidden');
});


$(document).keydown(function() {
   if($('#infocontent').hasClass('cnthidden')) {
      $('#infocontent').show();
   }
});
```

You where checking if the element had the class when it first loaded and it didn't. You add the class in a click handler and so need to check for it within the `keydown` function. Also you need to bind the `keydown` function to an element. `document` has been used in my example.

[Examplie JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFPKF/)